# How to save multi-output predicted masks into two different folders after using model.predict_generator

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, image-preprocessing, image-segmentation

I have a multi output segmentation task, the training process went well, but when Im trying to get the prediction I found difficulties to separate the two output into two different folders, in my dataset I have one image and two relating masks, I used this test generator:

```
def testGenerator(test_path= "data/membrane/test/image",num_image = 1584,target_size = (224,224),flag_multi_class = False,as_gray = False):
  for i in range(num_image):
    img = io.imread(os.path.join(test_path,"%d.jpg"%i),as_gray = as_gray)
    img = img / 255.
    img = trans.resize(img,target_size)
    img = np.reshape(img,img.shape) if (not flag_multi_class) else img
    img = np.reshape(img,(1,)+img.shape)
    yield img
```

and this is the code for `model.test_generator`:

```
testGene = testGenerator("data/membrane/test/image")
model = new_model()
model.load_weights("new_model.hdf5")
(conv11, convc11) = model.predict_generator(testGene,10,verbose=1)

saveResult(conv11,"data/membrane/test/results/road")
saveResult(convc11,"data/membrane/test/results/cl")
```

for visualization I used this :

```
def labelVisualize(num_class,color_dict,img):
    img = img[:,:,0] if len(img.shape) == 3 else img
    img_out = np.zeros(img.shape + (3,))
    for i in range(num_class):
    img_out[img == i,:] = color_dict[i]
    return img_out / 255

def saveResult(save_path,npyfile,flag_multi_class = False,num_class = 2):
    for i,item in enumerate(npyfile):
    img = labelVisualize(num_class,COLOR_DICT,item) if flag_multi_class else item[:,:,0]
    io.imsave(os.path.join(save_path,"%d_predict.tif"%(i)),skimage.img_as_ubyte(img))
```

Answer (score 0):

solve it, I just did this change:

from:

```
saveResult(conv11,"data/membrane/test/results/road")
saveResult(convc11,"data/membrane/test/results/cl")
```

to :

```
saveResult("data/membrane/test/results/road", conv11)
saveResult("data/membrane/test/results/cl",convc11)
```

and Ive got each output saved into different folders